# Best techniques to ajaxify Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm currently ajaxifying my Rails app as follows.

**JS**

application.js

```
$("a").live("click", function() {
      $.getScript(this.href);
      //do something
       return false;
    });
```

**Views**

index.js.erb

```
$("#core").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index') %>");
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'index' %>
```

_index.html.erb

```
#my partial
```

So when a user clicks a link, it will be intercepted and the corresponding js file will be executed, which renders a partial in a div. This means that, for each action, I will need 3 views, say index.js.erb, _index.html.erb, and index.html.erb.

This is painstaking to set up, and the index.html.erb file is somewhat useless, it just renders the partial (perhaps there's a way to render a full view from another view directly, hence eliminating the need for a partial?).

Is this the best way to do things? How do you usually imbricate Ajax with Rails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript MVC seems like it works well with MVC style backends. It standardizes ajax calls, controllers and views in a similar way that you are showing above:

http://javascriptmvc.com/